# Placing U3D file is giving me keyval package error

Tags: movie15

I'm quite new to LaTex, so my code is very simple, straight from MeshLab, generated while exporting as U3D, which I was planing to insert in my pdf:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\includemovie[
    poster,
    controls,
    label=cube.u3d,
    text=(cube.u3d),
    3Daac=60.000000, 3Droll=0.000000, 3Dc2c=-91.924004 84.159401 -64.042999, 3Droo=140.122559, 3Dcoo=-0.000000 0.000000 0.000000,
    3Dlights=CAD,
    ]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}{cube.u3d}
\end{document}
```

This is final part of .log:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \message 
l.14    ]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}{cube.u3d}
                                         
? q
OK, entering \batchmode...
 File ignored
! Extra \endcsname.
\KV@split ...csname \KV@prefix \@tempa \endcsname 
                                                  \ifx \@tempc \relax \KV@er...
l.14    ]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}{cube.u3d}
                                         
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.


! Package keyval Error: \message {File ignored} undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Answer (score 1):

Package `movie15` is outdated and not maintained anymore. Use pkg `media9` instead. It allows you to find good values for 3D view settings via the right click menu "Generate Default View" which becomes available after activating the 3D object in Acrobat Reader. Copy the proposed settings into your document source and re-run `latex`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\noindent\includemedia[
  %label=cube.u3d,
  3Dtoolbar,
  width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  3Dmenu, % gives you right click menu: "Generate Default View", among others
  %3Daac=..., % to be found with --------^^^^ 
  %3Dlights=...,
]{}{cube.u3d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves all of my issues